# What is the difference between `void f1(const Class &c)` and `void f2(Class const &c)`?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between these below functions ( Look at keyword `const` ) ?

```
void f1(const Class &c)
```

and

```
void f2(Class const &c)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. The two versions are interchangeable.

Comment: Except for the name of the function :)

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between `const Class&` and `Class const&`; likewise, there is no difference between `const Class*` and `Class const*`. Both denote a reference/pointer to a constant `Class` instance.

However, `Class* const` is a totally different beast. That is a const pointer to a non-const `Class` instance.

Comment: I was never aware of the second one (`Class* const`)... Makes it understandable why some people like to put the class/type name before `const`...

Answer (score 4):

(pedantic answer):

The difference is the name.

The name `f1` will differ from `f2` - even after mangling

The signatures are exactly the same, so otherwise there would be no difference

Comment: I looked at it :) _And_ I gave the correct answer. Did I miss something else?

Comment: Note, for trivia, that even `void f1(int)` and `void f1(int const)`, `void f1(int const a)`, `void f1(int const b)`, `void f1(const int)` are all perfectly interchangeable identical signatures (i.e. for overloading purposes and consequently name mangling)

Answer (score 2):

They're not different at all. Look at points 18.6 and 18.8 in [this page](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.6) for more info.